# Ethernet conection not working Atheros AR8152 OS 12.04

Tags: networking, 12.04, atheros, ethernet

I have instaled Ubuntu 12.04 but my network conection doesn't work and i know it's becouse of the drivers

I've run

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet
```

and this is the result

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
```

and even ifconfig -a and lspci -v and posted it in paste bin

[ifconfig -a and lspci -v](http://pastebin.com/7Mb9ZnXp)

I try to fix it by dowloading this drivers

[Drivers Website](http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/)

and instaling them with this commands

```
$ tar -xjvf compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2
$ cd compat-wireless*
$ scripts/driver-select atl1c
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo modprobe atl1c
```

but it fails in the last one becouse it cant find atl1c

with compat-wireless-2012-04-26-pc.tar.bz2 it complete the modprobe but the conection dont works

Please, I need a solution. I dont know what else to do for making this work

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem, no networks detected at all with my Asus eee pc. After a very frustrating day trying everything I did the below and my netbook immediately found my wireless network:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd ~/Downloads # [or wherever you download it to]
tar-xjvf compat-wireless-2012-04-26.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless*
scripts/driver-select ath9k
make
sudo make install
```

`atl1c` did not work for me; `ath9k` did.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. It worked for an AR8152 v1.1 (as opposed to your v2.0) - perhaps it will work for you.

1. Go to linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/
2. Download the most recent ( compat-wireless-2012-04-26.tar.bz2 )

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
cd ~/Downloads # [or wherever you download it to]
tar-xjvf compat-wireless-2012-04-26.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless*
scripts/driver-select atl1c
make
sudo make install
```

Then just reboot.

Comment: If you can see the only difference with the what i did is that you've installed built-essential using an internet conection but i dont have one

Comment: compat-wireless-2012-07-03.tar.bz2 does not work either for the v2.0 adapter. It builds, installs and even loads the module, but network is still unfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for my Acer e443. The LAN never worked until I installed the correct driver.

The correct one for me was:

Install build-essential from .deb file.
Download driver file:
http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/

```
cd ~/Downloads 
tar-xjvf compat-wireless-2012-04-26.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless*
scripts/driver-select atl1c
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe atl1c
```